Why is a key marked as a "Personal Key" in gpg?
In my list of keys visible when I do gpg --list-keys, one key that I have revoked is marked with "(Personal Key)", which comes after my user id name and before my email. What does this phrase mean? How do I change my current key to be my "Personal Key"?

If you revoked the key, why would you want to use it? Can you provide a screenshot of the UI for context purposes?

Ramhound, I belive the user is not very clear, he probably want to use another key as is personnal key and not the one he deleted, yet we need more detail.

@Ramhound: A likely guess is that they still want to be able to decrypt their old mail encrypted with that key, but not receive new mail.

@Ramhound sorry to be unclear. I have successfully revoked the old key. I don't want to use it anymore. However, in the UI produced by gpg --list-keys, I see the old one marked with this phrase "(Personal Key)". I'm trying to understand what that means, why it is marking only the revoked key, and how I can mark my current non-revoked key as my Personal Key if that is important.


Why is a key marked as a "Personal Key" in gpg?

It's marked that way because you've entered the phrase Personal Key at GnuPG's Comment: prompt when generating the key – there really is nothing more to it than that.

What does this phrase mean?

It means absolutely nothing as far as GnuPG is concerned, since it's not a special marker but literally part of the "Name" string.
Some PGP users use the comment field to more clearly distinguish personal keys from work keys or special-purpose keys (it's generally wise to keep them separate), e.g. I've seen a few "(Red Hat)" or "(Google work key)" or "(new 2011 key)"; some use it to add a nickname they're recognized by.

How do I change my current key to be my "Personal Key"?

You can use gpg --edit-key to add a new "User ID" with the new values; you might also need to use --expert depending on the GnuPG version (newer versions discourage using the comment field). Most other PGP software will have an option to add new UIDs.
The old UID will remain attached to the key unless you revoke it. (Even if you revoke it, old UIDs stay around in keyservers and in everyone's keyrings, so it results in a bit of clutter.)
Any existing "Web-of-Trust" signatures will likewise remain attached to the old UID – they will not carry over to the new one (as their whole purpose is to certify information in the UID).
So I would recommend just keeping the key as-is. You gain nothing by creating a new UID merely to add a comment, and it will only result in clutter (and possibly confusion later on).
